# Excel VBA: Loop InputBox and add values to cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub ChangeAccountNames_Click()

Dim AccountName As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputQuestion As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Worksheet

Set s = Sheets("Essential Info")
i = Cells(3, 9)

Do

Set Rng = Sheets("Essential Info").Range("I2:I13")
InputQuestion = "Please enter in a bank account name: " & vbNewLine & "Click Close once you are done"
AccountName = InputBox(InputQuestion)
Rng.Value = AccountName
i = i + 1

Loop Until i = 10

End Sub
```

What I need it to do in the following order is:

1. Open Inputbox when button is clicked - Done
2. Ask the user to enter in an account name - Done
3. Store the account name in a string - Done (AccountName Variable)
4. Write the AccountName to cell I3 in the sheet "Essential Info"- **Kinda works. It inserts to the right sheet but writes it to all cells I3:I13, believe its the Do loop being laid out wrong**
5. Shift cell I3 down so it now becomes I4 ready for the next name input- **Not Functional, need help. Was thinking that I may be able to add 1 cell to a Cells(0,0) variable?**
6. Only allow the cell to go up to I13 - **Working?? Stores this value in i and does count up each loop, it doesn't overshoot.**
7. Loop back to step 1 until i hits the limit defined OR the user closes the InputBox - **It loops but i believe the loop where all my issues lie**

There are currently unused variables and really messy bits of info in here that I've added as personal placeholders. Stepthrough seems to behave almost how I need it too but I know this is completely messy

Comment: I think each one of these questions should be a separate question here on SO. IT's a little broad to answer in one shot. You declare `rng` as `Range("I2:I13")` but you want to write to `I3`. Why is `I2` part of that range? Why is `I4:I13` part of that range? What good is having all of those cells hanging out in this one range variable good for? If you are stuck on using that `rng` as is then you can reference the exact cell you want to write to `Rng.Cells(2).Value = AccountName` However, why not just `Sheets("Essential Info").Range("I3").Value = AccountInfo` Isn't that a lot more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're looking to do, you should only be setting the `Rng` to the starting *cell* instead of the complete range. The quick fix is to set the initial position *outside* the loop and keep it in sync with `i` by offsetting the column.

To allow for an early exit if you don't get a value from the user in the `InputBox`, just check the return value for a `vbNullString`.

I'm guessing you need something more like this (untested):

```
Set Rng = Sheets("Essential Info").Range("I2")
Do
    InputQuestion = "Please enter in a bank account name: " & vbNewLine & "Click Close once you are done"
    AccountName = InputBox(InputQuestion)
    If AccountName <> vbNullString Then
        Rng.Value = AccountName
        i = i + 1
        'Offset by Row down
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0)
        'Offset by column right 
        'Set Rng = Rng.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
Loop Until i = 10 Or AccountName = vbNullString
```

Comment: This does the job. I edited the Rng.Offset to offset by rows instead of the specified columns. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @Batteredburrito Nice catch on my rows\columns mistake and thanks for the edit.