# VBA Excel add value and formula beyond the last row created by the loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to populate the total amount[image] summary after the last row generated by the loop, as per below:

where all the rows are based on the amount of the cell located at the different sheet ("Frontsheet").

The initial code for the [loop with copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634903/number-of-rows-based-on-the-cell-value-loop-with-copy) looks as follows:

```
   Dim i As Long

   Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet")
   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
   Set rg = ws1.Range("D32")
   Set rg2 = ws2.Range("B3:N3")

   For i = 1 To rg

   rg2.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B4").Resize(RowSize:=rg.Value)

   Next i
```

The code, which I built including the option which I want looks as follows:

```
Sub Address()

   Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

   Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet")
   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
   Set rg = ws1.Range("D32")
   Set rg2 = ws2.Range("B3:N3")
   Set rg3 = Cells("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rg4 = Cells("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set LastRow = Cells("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

   For i = 1 To rg

   rg2.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B4").Resize(RowSize:=rg.Value)
   Next i

   rg3.Value = "Total"   
   rg4.Value = "=SUM(J3: & Lastrow)"
   End Sub
```

It was based on the hints here:

[counting a range (rows) begingin in B3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976426/counting-a-range-rows-begingin-in-b3)

[Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

[Excel VBA: Loop InputBox and add values to cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655711/excel-vba-loop-inputbox-and-add-values-to-cell-range)

in order to find the last row.

Unfortunately I am getting an error:  **Invalid or unqualified reference** where the debugger points the following line:

```
    Set rg3 = Cells("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row,   especially .Rows
```

As per the explanation above I should have the `With` statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-or-unqualified-reference

But it looks like it complicates my situation because I set it as the range.

How can I add some stuff beyond the last row, which was populated by the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach that will get you started. This code is open to improvements.

Some general suggestions:

- Name your procedures and your variables to something meaninful
- Indent your code
- Organize your logic in steps, this will give you clarity and help you if you need to debug it

---

**About your code:**

1. Defining the variables in this way can lead to errors

> Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
>
> Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range, rg4 As Range    Dim
> ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

2. With these two, you're setting a range to a number (row)

> Set rg3 = Cells("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    Set rg4 =
> Cells("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

3. This ain't the last row (is the previous one) so either the variable name or the formula are wrong

> Set LastRow = Cells("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

4. In here you're looping (or at least trying to), but you're not doing anything inside the loop because you're already defining the range size you want to copy

> For i = 1 To rg
>
> rg2.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B4").Resize(RowSize:=rg.Value)
> Next i

---

****Code:****

```
Public Sub CopyInitialRow()
    
    ' Get rows' size
    Dim frontRowSize As Long
    frontRowSize = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value
    
    ' Set the release sheet
    Dim releaseSheet As Worksheet
    Set releaseSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
    
    ' Set the source range
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = releaseSheet.Range("B3:N3")
    
    ' Set the target range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = releaseSheet.Range("B4").Resize(rowSize:=frontRowSize)
    
    ' Copy source to target range
    sourceRange.Copy Destination:=targetRange
    
    ' Get the last row on target sheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = releaseSheet.Cells(releaseSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Write total label and value
    releaseSheet.Range("I" & lastRow + 1).Value = "Total"
    releaseSheet.Range("J" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(J3:J" & lastRow & ")"
    
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thannk you.

If I would like to make a border around it, is it enough to type:

With releaseSheet.Range("I" & lastRow + 1)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous 
 .Weight = xlThin 
 .ColorIndex = 3 
 End With

Comment: Pls give a try and post another question if you need any help

Comment: OK, no worries :) Thanks again :)